# Angularjs custom ng-repeat tiles in responsive views

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I have these "tiles" which are created using ng-repeat as shown in code below. That part works fine and this question is really more geared towards why I cannot get the `<ul>` to center in smaller views for tablet and mobile like I can for the full view. Am using Bootstrap 3.x as well. Have tried over rides, but nothing seems to center these tiles. Will also show images below of different mobile views and then also full view and then my code.

At tablet, it should show 2 centered. It does show 2, but they are left justified as:

[image]

Then on mobile, should be 1 centered, but again, left justified as:

[image]

And now, on full view, you can see how they are centered within the parent container:

[image]

My code (HTML):

```
<div class="beneArea">
    <div class="beneHeading" style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <h1>My Benefit Statements</h1>
        <p>Click on a benefit tile to access more detailed information.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="beneArea col-md-12">
        <ul class="col-md-3" data-ng-repeat="benefit in ppt.Benefits" >
            <div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==1 && benefit.isPending==false && benefit.isOE==false && (benefit.benefit == 'HealthCare' || benefit.benefit == 'Health Care' || benefit.benefit == 'Limited')" >
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="#/statement?pid={{benefit.planId}}&bid={{benefit.benefitTypeId}}">
                  <card template1 ng-model="benefit"></card>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==1 && benefit.isPending==true && benefit.isOE==true && (benefit.benefit == 'HealthCare' || benefit.benefit == 'Health Care' || benefit.benefit == 'Limited')" >
                <card template1b ng-model="benefit"></card>
            </div>
            <div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==1 && benefit.isPending==true && benefit.isOE==false && (benefit.benefit == 'HealthCare' || benefit.benefit == 'Health Care' || benefit.benefit == 'Limited')" >
                <card template1c ng-model="benefit"></card>
            </div>
            <div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==1 && benefit.isPending==false && benefit.isOE==false && benefit.benefit == 'DayCare'" >
              <a style="text-decoration: none" href="#/statement?pid={{benefit.planId}}&bid={{benefit.benefitTypeId}}">
                <card template1d ng-model="benefit"></card>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="beneTile" ng-if="benefit.planTypeId==1 && benefit.isPending==true && benefit.isOE==false && benefit.benefit == 'DayCare'" >
              <card template1c ng-model="benefit"></card>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS that creates and manages these:

```
.beneArea {
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.beneHeading {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

.beneHeading h1 {
    color: #000000;
}

.beneHeading > p {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.beneArea {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.beneArea > ul {
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 285px;
    width: 285px;
    float: left;
}

.beneTile {
    max-height: 285px;
    max-width: 285;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    ul > .beneTile {
        max-height: 285px;
        max-width: 285px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div.beneArea > ul {
        max-height: 285px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

.beneTile:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? Have tried applying margin-left and margin-right auto as well as text-align: center to the `<ul>` with no luck as well as quite a few other things. Any input would be great! Thanks much.

Comment: Taking a stab - I think the float lefts may be causing you issues on the `ul` element. Better to let the bootstrap classes center the items. If you look closely, even your desktop version is not even left and right. As well, is there any reason here that it is a `ul` element, if it's not causing worse problems, it's not very semantic?

Answer (score 1):

Dan makes a good point here, about the way you have laid this code out.
Take a look at the **[FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/732rhzr8/)** I put together to help show what you can do here to center this at the Mobile view.

It is a little Angular using ng-repeat for this demo.

You will see I use a media break point and have the css control the **centerThis** class.

I do this with the following CSS.
Using :  **transform: translate(-50%);**

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
   .centerThis{
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%);
    }
}
```

The HTML with the ng-repeat would be like this...

```
<div class="container"  ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController'>
     <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 border-xs centerThis">
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-8 block-1 centerThis" ng-repeat='block in blocks'></div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

You will see I did not use the **ul** like you have in your code.

I hope this little demo helps you get back on track.

[image]